# PHP set Basic Authentication Header server side

Tags: php, html, authentication, basic-authentication

I am currently stuck with a annoying problem. I tried writing a PHP script which compares two HTML pages for their differences, which works just fine. The result is echoed to the user so he can see the result diff. 
At this point a problem arises because some of the elements in the page are linked to a resource which requires basic authentication:

```
<img src="http://example.com/myImage"/>
```

When I open the page I get flooded with dialogues asking me to provide the basic authentication for all the elements in the page.

Since I know the required authentication data my question is if it is possible to preset it for the user using php.

I tried something along of the lines of:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']="user";
```

but that did not work at all.

Comment: Can't you just call the resource with the proper authentication information? `http://username:password@example.com/ `

Comment: how does the script get the html pages? via curl?

Comment: @KoenHollander no since Chrome 59 authorization in src and href tags are ignored

Comment: @Jeff yes I get both pages using curl, throw their source into a html diff lib and echo the result

Comment: So the result is interpreted as HTML by the browser? Is that desired? Don't you want to show the HTML source code without having it by parsed as HTML…?!

Comment: No, there is no other way to “pre-set” this, other than the `http://username:password@example.com/` syntax. It is still the user’s browser that is making the request for those resources, your PHP script has absolutely zeropointnothing to do with that.

Comment: @deceze no thats the point of the tool, kind of a preview

Comment: @misorude so there is absolutely no way to do it?

Comment: You could try and make an AJAX request for one of those “protected” images (if they are from the same domain, or CORS-enabled), and provide the auth credentials with that request - and _hope_ that the browser then stores them for the duration of the session, same as it would if the user entered them manually. But I am not sure if that works, you’d have to test it.

Comment: Wait I had an idea - what if I wrote a page which request the actual diff page but sets the authorization header? Could that work?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch) or exit(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

The above code snippet uses curl to execute a http request with basic authentication

Comment: Above answer depicts usage of curl to access resource with basic authentication which can be executed into background and return response

Comment: Powal as I said the problem ist not getting the page but the images etc within the page which get loaded by the browser